# Update Height with ViewFlipper

Tags: android, height, viewflipper

I want to be able to update height on every child of the ViewFlipper. Is this possible as I could never find any API documentation for ViewFlipper and updating the height or width.

Answer (score 22):

just use

```
ViewFlipper myflipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.myflipper);
myflipper .setMeasureAllChildren(false);
```

It will take height, and width of visible child only

Comment: Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

You're just going to have to loop through:

```
 LayoutParams myLP = new LayoutParams(myHeight, myWidth);
 for (int i = 0; i < myViewFlipper.getChildCount(); i++) {
      myViewFlipper.getViewAt(i).setLayoutParams(myLP);
 }
```